Mapbox wont change map colors
enter image description hereHi I'm trying to change some colors but mapbox wont do this.
I've searched across the internet and it seems that my code is right but changes wont take effect.
`
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'entidades',
        'source': 'estados',
        'source-layer': 'tasasyconteos_ent_updated-86v9k0',
        'maxzoom': zoomThreshold,
        'type': 'fill',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': ['interpolate', ['linear'],
                ['get', 'POBTOT'],
                0, '#f0f9e8',
                5000000, '#bae4bc',
                10000000, '#7bccc4',
                15000000, '#ff0000',
                25000000, '#0868ac'
            ],
            'fill-opacity': 1,
            'fill-outline-color': 'black'
        }
    }, 'road-label-simple');



Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
